# How to create dependent variable applications in Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to have three columns, price, cost, and margin. I want to be able to input numbers into two of the columns, and have it spit out whatever the third column should be. I then want to be able to change any column data and the other two columns will update accordingly.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Look into writing code for the worksheet's `Change` event.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Comment: Which formula do you use to calculate margin, if margin change what do you want to be change? Profit or Cost?

Comment: The problem is, you're typically only going to enter one value at a time and then the worksheet is going to calculate, therefore, it will need to calculate 2 cells.  That being the case, what's the sequence?  i.e. if you change the margin, should it try and calculate the price or the cost?  If you can define those rules, it's very much possible.